# Schengen tourist visa application

Tags: paperwork, schengen-visas, applications

I'm applying for my Schengen tourist visa at the end of next month. My cousin is sponsoring my trip as I'm still a student with no income.

How do I prove our relationship to the French embassy during the visa interview? We don't share a common surname, can a confirmation letter proving our relationship from a local administror be sufficient? Or is just stating on my cover letter and his sponsorship letter that we're cousins enough?

Comment: Are you in regular contact with your cousin? Does he/she provide you with any financial support other than for the planned trip? Being able to show a history of regular support and/or contact eg emails/sms/Skype etc might be useful in helping to show why your cousin would take on this commitment.

Comment: Yeah we're in regular contact, we communicate every other day and we see each other atleast every 2 months. He also supports my education by paying my school fees plus he has previously sponsored my trips to two neighbouring countries. I got bank statements to show his financial support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stating the relationship (and not just "cousin": it is a vague term) should be enough (e.g. it is the son of the brother of your father? [add names]).

But why you cousin want to sponsor you (and not me)? This is a question embassy want to know. They want to be sure you will comply with the visa (not working and returning within the visa timeframe). In Europe it is not frequent that a cousin will sponsor so much. Or are you paying your travel, and you the accommodation (and ev. food)? You should write it clearly. Note: he should not just have enough money to sponsor you, but also that such trip will not effect significantly his finances.

Too much documents seems to be seen as a bad sign (but I read this about US, where in person interview are preferred, and ev. they ask you for further documentation). Check the important documents.

From your history, you ask related visa question every month. I hope you are trying to get the perfect application. If you had few rejections, stop applying for the trip this September: every time you will get less and less possibilities (and it is suspicious).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, he's going to support all trip expenses plus I have some funds in my account that I have documentation proof for where they originated from. My cousin sponsors my education and lifestyle whilst I'm in school and I would say we're very fond of each other hence all the support he's giving. The trip won't hurt him financially at all. I've never applied for a Schengen visa nor gotten any rejection from any embassy, I just want to get well prepared for my visa.